# redirect http to https by using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, https, redirect

I added some lines in htaccess file but redirection still not happened.
My htaccess file:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
 RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
# BEGIN WordPress
# END WordPress
```

Comment: try `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1`

Comment: I tried that but nothing changed

Comment: have you access to the Apache error log on the server?